# The system reserved partition and volume "C:\" have same Unique id if the system disk is dynamic in Windows 2016

Tags: c++, windows, wdk

The system is Windows Server 2016, and I have changed the system disk from basic to dynamic, then traversed all the volumes to get the unique id.

I used the following code to get the unique id of the system volumes:

```
    flag = DeviceIoControl(volumeguid,
                IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID,
                NULL,
                0,
                uniqueid,
                sizeof(MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID) + BUF_SIZE,
                &result,
                NULL);
```

The GUID path of system volume C:

```
\\?\Volume{8bea1f4c-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\
```

The GUID path of system reserved partition:

```
\\?\Volume{8bea1f4c-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
```

And the Unique id returned for both volumes is:

```
4D440018-4F49-493A-443A-4C1FEA8B0000
```

It is abnormal.

But before I converted the system disk to dynamic, the unique id of the system reserved partition and volume "C:\" are different.

I want to know why the system reserved partition and system volume C have same unique ID when the system disk is changed to dynamic disk in Windows Server 2016.
But the unique ids are different before I changed the system disk to dynamic, at that time the system disk is basic.

And I have tested in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012, there doesn't have the same unique id problem when system disk was dynamic.

If someone can tell me the reason I will appreciate it.

Comment: Windows Server 2016, presumably?

Comment: The unique ID of a volume is not a GUID, unlike the mount-manager assigned volume GUID name, and it shouldn't be represented as a GUID. It's just an arbitrary byte sequence -- at least 4 bytes I think. For some volumes, the unique ID is a path in the object namespace as a UTF-16 string, and it's much longer than a 16 byte GUID. The mount manager associates the unique ID of a volume device with its assigned names -- the non-persistent NT device name and the persistent device names (GUID and DOS drive).

Comment: @ErykSun
Yes, of course, the unique ID of a volume is not a GUID.
the \\?\Volume{8bea1f4c-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\
and the \\?\Volume{8bea1f4c-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\ are GUID path, and the {4D440018-4F49-493A-443A-4C1FEA8B0000} is unique ID.
I have explained in question.

Comment: @ErykSun
The unique id "{4D440018-4F49-493A-443A-4C1FEA8B0000}" I said before was obtained by 
DeviceIoControl with GUID path and "IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID" prameters.

Comment: Anyway, check  "HKLM\System\MountedDevices". The unique ID may be associated there with the GUID name if the mount manager isn't implicitly deriving the volume GUID name in some other way.

Comment: @ErykSun I have checked the output value uniqueid. 
Found that uniqueid->UniqueIdLength = 24, and then copy the fist 16 bytes of uniqueid to a GUID object named uniqueidguid, then change the uniqueidguid to string and return it.
So maybe the uniqueid is different with each other, but the first 16 bytes of unique id of system reserved partition and system volume C are identical.

Comment: @ErykSun
How to change the 24 bytes uniqueid to string without copying the first 16 bytes of it to GUID object?